# MpdfException IMAGE Error () : Error parsing image file - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I'm stuck in very awkward situation where Images are being shown in Local Environment while generating PDF. But, Not in Production. **Images being displayed as [X] when to generate PDFs with mPDF.**

After inserting `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;` in **Controller**.

```
public function actionExportCasesPdf($id) {
  .
  .
  .
  .
  $mpdf = new \mPDF();
  $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($output);
  $mpdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
}
```

**Error**

> **MpdfException**
>
> IMAGE Error (..17.jpg): Error parsing image file - image type not
>   recognised, and not supported by GD imagecreate

Even, GD library is installed in the server using `apt-get install php5-gd` command. And, Image Path are also used correct.

I tried to keep image source as such. But, No Luck.

```
<img src="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to('@web/images/logo.png', true) ?>" width="100" alt="logo" />
```

I searched and tried the solution given by these links. But, still no luck :

1. [Images not showing on production but they do on local environment - GitHub](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/issues/19)
2. [mPDF 5.7.1 - image displays as a broken [x]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092683/mpdf-5-7-1-image-displays-as-a-broken-x)
3. [Generated picture in mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543677/generated-picture-in-mpdf)
4. [Error parsing image file](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-parsing-image-file/)

Any help/hint/suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: Does the same happen with different image resolutions and extensions?

Comment: Also - is local env Linux as well?

Comment: @Bizley . Yes it happens with every image resolution and extensions. And, local environment is Linux.

Comment: @Nana Partykar : try something like this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543677/generated-picture-in-mpdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It throws one new **error**

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

So, **problem was** : server was secured with password. So, I searched for it to find the way. And, [File-get-contents failed to open stream Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566487/file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-unauthorized) is having correct answer related to above error.

```
http://user_name:password@your_site.com/append_your_url
```

After appending `user name`, `password` and `site name` as above, It worked correctly.

**Related Search**

1. [Images not showing on production but they do on local environment - GitHub](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/issues/19)
2. [mPDF 5.7.1 - image displays as a broken [x]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092683/mpdf-5-7-1-image-displays-as-a-broken-x)
3. [Generated picture in mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543677/generated-picture-in-mpdf)
4. [Error parsing image file](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-parsing-image-file/)

Comment: Yes. After keeping this code. All issues were fixed.

Comment: HI How did you solve this, I am also facing an issue with my code.
its giving error: 
Error Here:  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED at http://usernam:pwd@%@http://example.com/wiki135

Comment: For me, this problem showed up as an incompatible image error -  when it was actually an access issue. I store images (apache environment) in `/assets/images`; I had to add that path to `php_admin_value open_basedir` - then everything worked and error messages vanished. MPDF v8, PHP v7.4

Answer (score 3):

Most probably the picture is not available for MPDF via the generated URL.
Let's try to debug it :) Run the following code on both local and prod environments

```
$imageUrl = \yii\helpers\Url::to('@web/images/logo.png', true);
$image = file_get_contents($imageUrl);
echo (new \finfo())->buffer($image);
// echo $image; 
// ^^ uncomment, if previous line echoed something not image-related. 
// Maybe, you've got 404 error
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort @brother.

Answer (score 2):

mpdf is not fetching transparent image while generating pdf, so make sure your image is not transparent.

It's working on my localhost but issue with aws server. 
Apart from aws it's work fine. 
Gd library is not allow to parse transparent iamge.

Answer (score 0):

if you use cpanel on your server go to Hotlink Protection and active **Allow direct requests (for example, when you enter the URL of an image in a browser)**.
but your Privacy Policy must allow it
[screenshot form this section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xTs9.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Special case**

In my case my SSL certificate got expire so I renewed it. My application is hosted on AWS ( classic load balancer).

After upgrading SSL certificate everything start working but MPDF start giving error for image files.

After 3-4 hours I just try with delete ssl certificate using AWS Certificate Manager and import again same certificate. **Magic happen and now its working.**